# Vanishing of (p,q)-cohomology of compact homogeneous Kähler manifolds

Tags: reference-request, cohomology, kahler-manifolds

Let $G$ be a semisimple compact Lie group and $M$ be a compact $G$-homogeneous manifold equipped with a equivariant complex structure. I know that all non-vanishing cohomology classes lives in $H^{(p,p)}$ for $p \leq \dim M$. Where can I find a reference for this fact?

Thank you very much.